# How to check for part of a string within a list?

Tags: python, string, list

What is the most efficient way to check for part of a string within a list?

For example, say I am looking for "4110964_se" (True) or "4210911_sw" (False) in the following list:

```
files = ['H:\\co_1m_2013\\41108\\m_4110864_se_12_1_20130717.tif',
         'H:\\co_1m_2013\\41108\\m_4110864_sw_12_1_20130717.tif',
         'H:\\co_1m_2013\\41109\\m_4110964_se_12_1_20130722.tif']
```

If I use a simple check, the results are not what I would expect:

```
>>> "4110964_se" in files
False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
any('4110964_se' in f for f in files) # check if the string is in any of the list items
```

Answer (score 1):

Malik Brahimi's answer works, though another way of doing this is just to put the files in a for loop like this:

```
for f in files:
    print "4110964_se" in f
```

The reason your solution doesn't work is because it only looks for items that have the exact value "4110964_se", rather than looking in each string to see if that value is anywhere in any of the strings. For example, if you did:

```
print "H:\\co_1m_2013\\41108\\m_4110864_se_12_1_20130717.tif" in files
```

It would print True, because you gave it the full file name, rather than just a piece of it

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for x in files:
    if '4110964_se' in x:
        bool('4110964_se')
```

It prints:

```
True
```