# Check if Python input contains a list of keywords

Tags: python, input, keyword-search

AKA the correct version of this:

```
if ['hi', 'hello', 'greetings'] in userMessage:
    print('Hello!')
```

I tried what's showed above but it says it cannot use lists, it must use a single string. Same thing if I set the array to an object/variable. If I use "or" it doesn't seem to work altogether.

Comment: You want it the other way around.. `if userMessage in ['hi', 'hello', 'greetings']:`

Comment: Translate it logically. If `message` in some list of messages. No more complicated than that.

Comment: It follows the same in english.. `if item in listOfItems:`

Comment: I think the OP wants all keywords in the `userMessage`, is that right @GabeWeiner ?

Comment: sorry I didn't specifiy, I meant if one of them was present print the result

Comment: What is the type of `userMessage`?

Comment: this is for a simple chat bot im making for the practice, so the user inputs whatever they want and my goal is to have the code look for keywords to choose a response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for part of a string within a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436392/how-to-check-for-part-of-a-string-within-a-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the goal is just to say if any of the known list appears in `userMessage`, and you don't care which one it is, [use `any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions):

```
if any(srchstr in userMessage for srchstr in ('hi', 'hello', 'greetings')):
```

It will short-circuit when it gets a hit, so if `hi` appears in the input, it doesn't check the rest, and immediately returns `True`.

If the words must be found as individual words (so `userMessage = "This"` should be false, even though `hi` appears in it), then use:

```
if not {'hi', 'hello', 'greetings'}.isdisjoint(userMessage.split()):
```

which also short-circuits, but in a different way; it iterates `userMessage.split()` until it matches one of the keywords, then stops and returns `False` (which the `not` flips to `True`), returning `True` (flipped to `False` by `not`) only if none of the words matches a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
found = set(['hi','hello','greetings']) & set(userMessage.split())
for obj in found:
    print found
```

if you are looking for multiple words as well

Comment: `set` is already a builtin Python type. Just use `set(lst)`, and then a set intersection is a good way to go for it.

Comment: Also, one more thing before I give it a "+1", cause this the correct answer, line one of your code snippet has a SyntaxError due the trailing `:`

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: You could also avoid converting the `list` to a `set` at all (and use literals, because why make a `list` only to immediately convert it to a `set`) with `found = {'hi','hello','greetings'}.intersection(userMessage.split())`; the named methods accept any iterable, not just sets, and (implementation detail) don't convert it to a `set` even internally, instead just iterating it and membership testing against the original `set` to determine if it belongs in the result `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare multiple elements using Set:

```
if set(['hi', 'hello', 'greetings']) <= set(userMessage.split()):
   print("Hello!")
```

But be careful to use split(), once it will not avoid ponctuation. So, if your userMessage is something like "hi, hello, greetings." it will compare the words against ["hi,", "hello,", "greetings."]

Comment: This tests if *all* of the words are in `userMessage`, not just one; the OP [specifically asked for it to be true "if one of them was present print the result"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602571/check-if-python-input-contains-a-list-of-keywords/34602889#comment56951130_34602571). To make it work for just one, you'd need something like `if not {'hi', 'hello', 'greetings'}.isdisjoint(userMessage.split()):`; `isdisjoint` returns `True` when there is no overlap, so flipping it (with `not`) tells you at least one was present.